# Trouble understanding an anonymous function

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, function-handle

I do not understand the following code:

```
rect2rng = @(pos,len)ceil(pos):(ceil(pos)+len-1);
```

From the the previous link:

[BoundingBox Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664725/boundingbox-matlab/35670955?noredirect=1#comment59098207_35670955)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) is a short-hand way of defining a function. It accepts input arguments (`pos` and `len`) and produces a result.

The general format is:

```
func = @(input,arguments)some_action(input, arguments)
```

This creates an anonymous function called `func` and can then be used (just like any other function) by passing it input arguments

```
value1 = 1;
value2 = 2;
output = func(value1, value2)
```

The long-form function equivalent above the above example would be:

```
function output = func(input, arguments)
    output = some_action(input, arguments);
end
```

So with this in mind, we can break down the anonymous function in your question into a normal function

```
function output = rect2rng(pos, len)
    output = ceil(pos):(ceil(pos) + len-1);
end
```

So based on this, it rounds `pos` up to the nearest integer using `ceil` and then creates an array of length `len` starting as this rounded value.

So if we pass it some test inputs we can see it in action.

```
rect2rng(1.5, 3)
%// [2  3  4]

rect2rng(1, 3)
%// [1  2  3]

rect2rng(10, 5)
%// [10  11  12  13  14]
```